# SQL Query string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to load a table from an SQL onto a datatable in a c# application.
There is a very similar question which answered to question of how to do that. the question I have however is at the moment I have the entity relationship diagram on my wall for the database I'm trying to connect to so i know the table name but i Don't know what to prefix it.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM dstut.dbo.[" + table + "]";
```

From the other post I know that it should look like this but with my databases Equivalent of the dstut.dbo. unfortunately my boss isn't here and I don't have access to the database. Is there anyway I can bypass that and connect with just the name of the table?

Comment: *Is there anyway I can bypass that and connect with just the name of the table?* Did you try that? Any problem or error?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes i get an error of: Incorrect syntax near 'tblUser'.

Comment: When you say you don't have access to the database... do you mean you don't know the username and password required to connect to it? You would need that information, and then use it in your connection string.

Comment: So what is your query then?

Comment: @ChristopherLake I have a connectionstring which contains a user and password. Is there any way i can use that to find out what I need ?

Comment: can you attach some screen shot of error and let us know what actually resolve for table variable in your dynamic query ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman are you asking what is my query as in my question or as in my SQL query because both of them are addressed in the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman dont worry thats me being stupid i assume you mean without the variable?

Comment: @Prashant-Systematix unfortunatley i cant i dont have 10 reputation, ill try and link them in the comments: https://prntscr.com/ejsjfp , http://prntscr.com/ejskp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See as per your screen prntscr.com/ejskp4 the your query is not making correctly

Your query: Select * [tblUser].

But Actually it should be resolve like : Select * From [tblUser]

try to make the query properly as per SQL syntax then it will not give you any error.

Thanks

Comment: Ahh, well don't I feel ridiculous. worked perfectly thank you.